# Using update with SQLMAP error

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sqlmap

I am trying to use UPDATE or insert after getting victim database information,  for that I am using command:

```
sqlmap -u somewebsite.com/id=2  --sql-shell
```

After  that:

```
> sql-shell :  UPDATE username FROM ....
```

and I get an error everytime (also in other websites):

```
execution of custom SQL queries is only available when stacked queries are supported
```

And if I type

```
SELECT username FROM ...
```

I get correct results.

I've tried to google much about this, but no luck,  if possible give me some advice to update victim's database.  Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Now, this is... ekhm... not the best place to ask SQL syntax questions.

The UPDATE operation does not have a `FROM` keyword in SQL.  In other words a SELECT operation looks as follows:

```
SELECT username FROM user_table WHERE user_id = 1;
```

But the UPDATE operation is:

```
UPDATE user_table SET username = 'myuser' WHERE user_id = 1;
```

(which turns to be quite different form your: `UPDATE username FROM ...`)

So yeah, `sqlmap` is seeing two queries: an UPDATE (thanks to the `UPDATE` keyword) and a SELECT (thanks to the `FROM` keyword).  Most SQL injections do not allow for stacked (multiple) queries.  See [this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/71402/sql-injection-with-single-statement-query) about the availability of stacked queries in SQL injections.